# Cannot run apt-get update in docker

Tags: linux, macos, docker, ubuntu, apt

I am having issues connecting with apt-get from a Docker image. To recreate, I can run

`sudo docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash`

and then type:

`apt-get update`

Without fail, the machine is unable to connect and I get a series of errors that look like this:

`Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out`

I am running an M1 Macbook Pro and have tried:

- Changing DNS settings
- Other docker base images
- I'm able to successfully download from other sources (eg. pip install)
- Disabling IPv6
- Trying another wi-fi network (I'm not behind any firewalls)

None of this has helped so far, and I have been completely unable to `apt-get update` or `apt-get install` to work in a docker container. Would greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have Private Relay enabled. Disabling it solved for me, without factoring reset the MacBook Pro.

I had the same issue, where in Safari I could access `http://ports.ubuntu.com` but in Chrome or even `wget http://ports.ubuntu.com` was giving `connection timeout` on Docker.

Comment: What exactly does private relay do? Is there a reference that can be added to this answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
RUN apt-get update -y
```

Try to run this command and let me if it works

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty much the same issue on Macbook Pro M1 when running `apt-get update` in docker. I had previously built images using the same Dockerfile and it was working fine.

Tried a number of things (machine restart / reinstall Docker / removed antivirus) and the issue still remains (Timing out trying to reach a server).

Not ideal, but my workaround was to switch to an Alpine image and run

```
RUN apk update
RUN apk add <lib>
```

Luckily I was using `golang:1.19.7` which has an alpine tag `golang:1.19.7-alpine`.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that in docker run command you open the relevant ports, or just pass in net=host (forgot the syntax) to get full network access.

Answer (score -1):

Figured out I was able to load these URLs in Safari, but not Chrome – which tracks with an ongoing issue I’ve had with this new computer where some sites weren’t loading in Chrome. Do not know exactly what the issue was – probably some weird DNS thing – but a factory reset of my Mac solved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

First make sure you can `ping` to external services. May be try `ping google.com`.

If its not working, check firewall of you laptop. It may be blocking `apt` repo.

Alternately you can try two options. First using `Dockerfile` and then `docker build`

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt update
RUN apt install vim #or any package you want
```

Or, run the docker image, and then connect to that image and run.

`docker run --name my_ubuntu -d ubuntu`

`docker exec -it my_ubuntu /bin/bash`

And then try to run `apt update` command.

Comment: Hi Sachith – Yes I can ping to external services (although need to download a Docker image that already contains ping). I cannot run any `apt` or `apt-get` commands successfully though.

Comment: Hi @jeffstern how did you resolve?